# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when combining two Sets

Tags: java, collections, set

I have 2 different instances of HashMap

I want to merge the keysets of both HashMaps;

**Code:**

```
Set<String> mySet = hashMap1.keySet();
mySet.addAll(hashMap2.keySet());
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:238)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:322)
```

I don't get a compile warning or error.

From java doc this should work. Even if the added collection is also a set:

**boolean addAll(Collection c)**

> Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this set if
>   they're not already present (optional operation). If the specified
>   collection is also a set, the addAll operation effectively modifies
>   this set so that its value is the union of the two sets. The behavior
>   of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified
>   while the operation is in progress.

Comment: Note this can also happen if one of the sets is immutable

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you look at the docs of the [`HashMap#keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) method, you'll get your answer(emphasis mine).

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
>   vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is
>   in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the
>   results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element
>   removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the
>   Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear
>   operations. **It does not support the add or addAll operations.**

Therefore, you need to create a new set and add all the elements to it, instead of adding the elements to the `Set` returned by the `keySet()`.

Answer (score 34):

The result of [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) does not support adding elements to it.

If you are not trying to modify `hashMap1` but just want a set containing the union of the two maps' keys, try:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.addAll(hashMap1.keySet());
mySet.addAll(hashMap2.keySet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't support by nature of Set which is from map.keySet(). It supports only remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations.

Please read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are correct. If you still wants to know the exact implementation detail (jdk 8)

`hashMap1.keySet() returns a KeySet<E>`  and

```
KeySet<E>   extends AbstractSet<E>
AbstractSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
```

In AbstractCollection,

```
public boolean add(E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

`addAll() calls add()` and thats why you are getting an `UOException`

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own Set with the keys of the Map like this:

```
Set set = new HashSet(map.keySet());
```

Then you can add whatever you want to it.